# asp:textbox validation for integers and zero alone

Tags: javascript

I'm working on asp.net website.
I have asp:texbox. I need validate the text box at clientside using javascript.

I want to prevent the user from entering the values other than intergers and aslo from entering 0(zero) alone. I mean he should not enter only 0. 
How can I achieve pls help me.
and I just want to prevent the user and don't want to show error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using purely ASP.NET, this is what you're looking for:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTb" />
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="cmp1" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="myTb" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="A numeric value is required." />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv1" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="myTb" EnableClientScript="true" Text="*" ErrorMessage="A value is required." />
```

Very important to understand that using ASP.NET here isn't going to ignore non-numeric keystrokes.  It's going to prevent the user from submitting the form with non-numeric values in myTb, and it will stop myTb from submitting with its default value of 0.

UPDATE:  Here's an alternative using a custom validator that will allow you to enable the submit button on change when the textbox's text is valid - remember, this is onchange, not onkeydown/up, so the user must change focus (tab off of the textbox) before the validator will fire.  I'd recommend going with solution 1 if you're just starting out and not very comfortable with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mytb_customValidate(sender, args) {
    if (isNaN(args.Value)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else if (args.Value == 0) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    $get("btn1").disabled = args.IsValid ? "" : "disabled";
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTb" /> 
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cstv1" ClientValidationFunction="mytb_customValidate" EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="myTb" ValidateEmptyText="true" Text="*" ErrorMessage="A non-zero numeric value is required." />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Click Me!" Enabled="false"/>
```

One last quick update - to accomplish your goal of not showing any errors w/ the validation, simply remove the ErrorMessage= and Text= attributes from the asp:CustomValidator above...

Happy coding!

B

Comment: Hi brian thanks for ur code.Its working but instead of showing error message i need to disable the button if the textbox not valid correctly. How can I do that.is it possible with these serverside validation.

Comment: @user823017 - you'll have to throw some client script into the mix to toggle enabling/disabling the button.  Give me a few minutes and I'll post a solution for that w/ a custom validator...

Comment: Hi Brian I did some changes and its workig fine for me thanks a lot.

Comment: Brian if u don't mine how can I restrict the textbox to allow only integer values(like 105,4 etc not values like 4.5,2.0)

Comment: Are you asking for how to swap between locales?  Like, sometimes you want to validate numbers as 1.25, and other times like 1,25?  Or always 1,25?  If always, check your server - if the server's default locale is ES-sp, for example, you should already see validation working this way...

Comment: Yes, thats working for 1,45 like that but I I give num as 1.25 or 45.2 its not showing error instead btn become enabling.

Comment: Is your website in english?  What you're talking about is culture specific validation.  The culture used for validation will be dependant on:  Your server's default culture, your website's supported cultures, your client's language settings.  This is a pretty big topic - I'd suggest you start a new question or we enter a private chat to discuss further...

Comment: Ok my website in english only.

Comment: Yeah - if your site is in english but you want some other culture applied to validation best to post a new question so others will learn from it...  big topic...

Comment: Setting  InitialValue="0" is all I had to do to get this to work for me. Thanks!